# Map not adding click event handlers to markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

The code below will add markers to my map. But the add Listener event never gets added to each marker.

```
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById("google-map");
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'test'
    });

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv);
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(53.635784, 6.943359));
    map.setZoom(5);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var dataMarker = data[i];
        var marker = new GLatLng(dataMarker.Latitude, dataMarker.Longitude);
        map.addOverlay(new google.maps.Marker(marker, {
            title: dataMarker.Name,
            html: dataMarker.HtmlAttributes[0]
        }));
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {                
            infoWindow.setContent(this.html);
            infoWindow.open(map, this);
        });            
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Oh and I am using Maps v2.

Comment: Why are you developing new code in the _deprecated_ and _turned off_ [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not add any listener to  `marker`.

```
var marker = new GLatLng(dataMarker.Latitude, dataMarker.Longitude);
```

`marker` is not a  `google.maps.Marker` , it's a `google.maps.LatLng` , which will not respond to mouse-events, because it's not an UI-element, it's just a javascript-object

Answer (score 0):

You created event listeners which are most probably connected with last marker.

You have to link info window with marker in separate function. Last part of your code should be written as:

```
    addEventListener(marker, infoWindow, map);
}

function addEventListener(marker, infoWindow, map) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {                
        infoWindow.setContent(marker.html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });            
}
```

See also [An array of infoWindow in Google maps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087212/an-array-of-infowindow-in-google-maps-api) and link with explanation about closures.

Comment: No, that's not the case here. That can only happen if you refer to the variable from the loop (`marker`) from within a closure. The marker is being passed directly to `addListener` in this snippet, and is not directly referred to from within the closure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a mix of v2 and v3 code in that snippet, and so the whole thing is unlikely to work.

For example, you're using `new google.maps.Infowindow` (v3) in the same place as `GLatLng`.

My suggestion would be to change the bootstrap on the page to v3, and delete any references to v2 objects (like `GLatLng`). Make sure you're loading the API like this:

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?…"></script>
```